# QGIS 3.28 : Relational value form (spatial intersection)

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3, intersection, spatial-join

With QGIS 3.28 I have a point layer (boreholes) . And I have a polygonal layer (departments/districts). My goal would be to via QGIS (right click boreholes point layer  -> attributes form) to automatically fill  the "department" field of the boreholes layer. The filling would be done via spatial intersection. The field of the departments table that I would like to retrieve is called "nom_dep".

I am attaching a screenshot of my settings.
[image]
For the "layer" parameter, I filled the department layer
For the "key column" parameter, I entered the primary key (gid) of the department column
For the parameter column of values, I put the field "nom_dep" from the table of departments

I didn't fill in anything for the "Column description" parameter.

In the "Filter expression" section I filled like that:

```
aggregate(
layer:='AdminExpressDept_AOI_Po_20210331',
aggregate:='concatenate_unique',
expression:=attribute('dep_name'),
concatenator:=',',
filter:=intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry))
```

I have no error message. But it does not work. I do not see the values of departments entered in the field of the table of boreholes. Did I make a mistake? Should another QGIS filter expression be used?

Answer (score 2):

When you are in the Value Relation filter expression box the frame of reference/scope is actually that layer (i.e. your departments layer) - so for example `$geometry` returns a polygon geometry rather than any point geometry (or lack of geometry) from your point layer.

So you shouldn't need to use an extensive `aggregate()` function.

To extract any values from your currently edited feature (i.e. your borehole layer), you instead need to use the variables provided such as `@current_feature`.

Try the following, which should filter your departments layer by just checking whether each department's geometry intersects with the borehole point you've just digitised, and returning the matching features only.

```
intersects($geometry, @current_geometry)
```